# What does it mean TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am updating the value in data base and problem occurs. Here's the code.

```
def withdraw(self, withdraw_amount, acount_no ,name):
        self.withdraw_amount = withdraw_amount
        self.acount_no = acount_no
        self.name = name
        self.new_amount = 0
        cur.execute('SELECT Amount FROM Users WHERE Name=? AND Acount=?',(self.name,self.acount_no))

        self.new_amount=cur.fetchall[0][0] + self.withdraw_amount
        cur.execute('UPDATE Users SET Amount=? WHERE Name=? AND Acount=?(self.new_amount,self.name,self.acount_no,))
        con.commit()
```

Comment: You have a missing quote and comma in the 2nd `cur.execute`

Comment: Also i think you mean `cur.fetchall()[0][0]`